# Emacs org-mode org-capture: at beginning of headings?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to use org-capture in Emacs org-mode so that captured sub-headings are put at the beginning of a section?
How to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `:prepend` property should add your new sub-heading as the first child rather than the last.

Doc [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html#Template-elements).